# NGINX - url rewrite regular expression

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have the url such as `example.com/page.php?username=test`. I want to rewrite this url into something like: `example.com/test` only if `test` follows the following regual expression: `/^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,35}+$/`, else 404 page.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the quantifier you specified, what should `{1,35}+` mean? "1-35" or "1 or more"?

Comment: I mean 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16...35.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
    location /page.php {
      if ($args ~ "^username=([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,35})$")
      {  
        set $username $1;
        rewrite . /$username last;
      }  
      return 404;
    }
```

The trick is that in the `location` directive Nginx matches for the variable `$uri`, according to the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24uri) this variable does not include any get arguments. So the only way to achieve your goal is to first match for the uri `/page.php`, and then check the arguments in an `if` statement.

The reason why i had to do the `set $username $1;` instead of directly redirecting to the variable `$1` is that the `rewrite` directive itself matches for sub strings of the given pattern, so it overwrites the `$[0-9]` variables. So I had to use the temporary `$username` variable to keep the username.

You might want to do something else than `return 404;` in the case where somebody gets into the location `/page.php` but the value of the username parameter does not match the regular expression.